# Use selenium to choose dropdown value from multiple selects that have the same xpath

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, xpath

I'm trying to scrape data by python from this e-commerce [site](https://vinmart.com/Th%E1%BB%8Bt---Thu%E1%BB%B7-h%E1%BA%A3i-s%E1%BA%A3n---Tr%E1%BB%A9ng-c11720?p=1&_sort=discount&_order=desc)

Because it requires to select the shipping location first to access the data and the 3 selects have the same xpath so I use the code below

```
city = browser.find_element(By.XPATH,"(//select[not(@id) and not(@class)])[1]")
citydd = Select(city)
citydd.select_by_value('01') # Hanoi
time.sleep(1)

district = browser.find_element(By.XPATH,"(//select[not(@id) and not (@class)])[2]")
districtdd = Select(district)
districtdd.select_by_value('0101') # Ba Dinh
time.sleep(1)
    
ward = browser.find_element(By.XPATH,"(//select[not(@id) and not (@class)])[3]")
warddd = Select(ward)
warddd.select_by_value('010104') # Cong Vi

browser.find_element(By.XPATH,"//div[text()='Xác nhận']").click() # Xac nhan
```

It returns me this error

```
NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"(//select[not(@id) and not(@class)])[1]"}
```

May I know how to bypass this situation?

Comment: If you have same web element use Findelements method without findelement and store it in list

Comment: @JustinLambert do you mean
`location = browser.find_elements(By.XPATH,"//select[not(@id) and not(@class)]")
city = location[0]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is the ability to select better xpaths. You can use a relative xpaths using the `label` of associated `select`

```
//label[contains(text(),'Tỉnh/Thành phố')]/following-sibling::div/select
//label[contains(text(),'Quận/Huyện')]/following-sibling::div/select
//label[contains(text(),'Phường/Xã')]/following-sibling::div/select
```

This is the middle one identified as unique using the above:
[image]

If you're still getting no such error with these xpaths - please ensure you include [explicit or implicit waits](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/webdriver/waits/)

Selenium's default wait strategy is the "the page has loaded". Most often in modern pages, the page loads, THEN scripts run which get more data or display a modal (like the popup on the image). Those async calls cause fails as nosuchelements in selenium.

Let me know if you need more information on sycnhronisation.

Comment: I still get such error. This is how I edit the code. [image](https://i.imgur.com/es7XACu.png)

Answer (score 0):

This is what i have tried -

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from time import sleep
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)


driver.get('https://vinmart.com/')

FirstDropDown = Select(driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//select)[1]"))
FirstDropDown.select_by_index(1)
sleep(2)
SecondDropDown = Select(driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//select)[2]"))
SecondDropDown.select_by_index(1)
sleep(2)
ThirdDropDown = Select(driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//select)[3]"))
ThirdDropDown.select_by_index(1)
```

I have used `sleep()` because it will take time to populated data in the dropdown as per pervious dropdown selection.

Please mark it as answer if it resolves your problem.

Comment: Thank you I solved it! it turns out that my url is wrong!